# OpenXML SDK: Embedded OLE object shrinks after editing

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have to create a very large Word document which contains a lot of plots (yes, it HAS to be Word). The plots are generated by a third party application. Since the third party application only supports Word documents smaller than 8 MiB, and the documents I have to generate are much bigger, I am plotting the pictures to individual documents, one each, extract them afterwards, and add them to my final document.

The "picture format" they use is some proprietary stuff that is embedded via OLE. Double-clicking it opens an application in the background that allows zooming and panning in the picture. Now, when leaving this picture editor, the picture suddenly shrinks, destroying the layout of the document. The original document from where I extract the picture does not exhibit this behavior.

Currently, what I do is:

1. Plot the picture to a temporary document, let it be `temp.docx`
2. Open the `temp.docx` as a `WordprocessingDocument`
3. Extract the proprietary binary image data, let it be `plot.bin`
4. Extract its WMF representation, let it be `plot.wmf`
5. Search the corresponding `Shape` object, create a clone of its `Shapetype` child
6. Add the `plot.bin` as an `EmbeddedObjectPart`
7. Add the `plot.wmf` as an `ImagePart`
8. Create a `Shape` with an `ImageData` child referencing the id of `plot.wmf`
9. Create an `OleObject`
10. Add the picture to a paragraph as an appropriate `EmbeddedObject` part

When I look at the XML this generates, it looks identical to the original document.

Here is the code part:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a picture
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="doc">Document to add picture to</param>
    /// <param name="pictureFile">File with proprietary picture data</param>
    /// <param name="wmfRepresentationFile">WMF representation of the proprietary picture file</param>
    /// <param name="pictureNumber">A rising number of the embedded picture. Incremented upon
    /// embedding the picture!</param>
    private static void AddPicture(WordprocessingDocument doc,
                                   string pictureFile,
                                   string wmfRepresentationFile,
                                   Shapetype shapeType,
                                   ref int pictureNumber) {
        LOG.Debug("Embedding the picture in the document");
        var emObj = doc.MainDocumentPart.AddEmbeddedObjectPart("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleObject");
        using (var pictureIn = new FileStream(pictureFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (var oleOut = emObj.GetStream(FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)) {
            oleOut.Position = 0;
            pictureIn.CopyTo(oleOut);
            oleOut.Flush();
        }
        // An OLE embedded object also needs an image part.
        var image = doc.MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Wmf);
        using (var imageIn = new FileStream(wmfRepresentationFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (var imageOut = image.GetStream(FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)) {
            imageOut.Position = 0;
            imageIn.CopyTo(imageOut);
            imageOut.Flush();
        }
        // Get some IDs we need for the linking
        var objectPartId = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(emObj);
        var objectId = ("_" + emObj.GetHashCode().ToString() + "000000").Substring(0, 11);
        var imagePartId = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(image);
        // Create a new paragraph with the embedded object.
        // First, a "Shape"
        var shape = new Shape() {
            Id = "_x0000_i10" + pictureNumber,
            Style = "width:500.0pt;height:600.0pt", // Sets the size of the picture in the document
            Ole = new TrueFalseBlankValue(),
            Type = "#_x0000_t75",
        };
        // This must contain the "imagedata" - a link to the image representation of the
        // empty active picture
        shape.AppendChild(new ImageData() {
            Title = "",
            RelationshipId = imagePartId
        });
        // Now, the link to the active picture itself
        var ole = new OleObject() {
            Type = OleValues.Embed,
            ProgId = "Foo.Proprietary.Picture.1",
            ShapeId = "_x0000_i10" + pictureNumber,
            DrawAspect = OleDrawAspectValues.Content,
            ObjectId = objectId,
            Id = objectPartId
        };
        // Now, wrap everything into a Paragraph / Run / EmbeddedObject
        var pictureParagraph = new Paragraph(new Run(new EmbeddedObject(shapeType, shape, ole)));
        // And append it
        doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(pictureParagraph);
        // Increase the image counter
        pictureNumber++;
    }
```

What am I missing / doing wrong?